# VB.net only 32 bytes and less to search

Tags: vb.net, arrays, wildcard

this is a function to search for a byte pattern (in process memory) in an array of bytes.
where `SearchFor` is the array of bytes to look for. and `SearchIn`is the array of bytes dumped by the `ReadProcessMemory` external function. this is also done using Wildcard `"?"`.

problem is if the byte pattern length is less or equal to 32 it will search. else return intptr.zero. and im not sure why.

```
Private Function WildCard(ByVal SearchIn As Byte(), ByVal SearchFor As Byte()) As IntPtr
        Dim l As Integer = 0, m = 0
        Dim iEnd As Integer = SearchFor.Length
        Dim sBytes As Integer() = New Integer(&H100 - 1) {}
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To iEnd - 1
            If (SearchFor(i) = &H3F) Then
                l = (l Or (CInt(1) << ((iEnd - i) - 1)))
            End If
        Next i
        If (l <> 0) Then
            Dim j As Integer
            For j = 0 To sBytes.Length - 1
                sBytes(j) = l
            Next j
        End If
        l = 1
        Dim index As Integer = (iEnd - 1)
        Do While (index >= 0)
            sBytes(SearchFor(index)) = (sBytes(SearchFor(index)) Or l)
            index -= 1
            l = (l << 1)
        Loop
        Do While (m <= (SearchIn.Length - SearchFor.Length))
            l = (SearchFor.Length - 1)
            Dim length As Integer = SearchFor.Length
            Dim k As Integer = -1
            Do While (k <> 0)
                k = (k And sBytes(SearchIn((m + l))))
                If (k <> 0) Then
                    If (l = 0) Then
                        Return New IntPtr(m)
                    End If
                    length = l
                End If
                l -= 1
                k = (k << 1)
            Loop
            m = (m + length)
        Loop
        Return IntPtr.Zero
    End Function
```

Comment: Your code is hard to follow. Please rename the variables to be more descriptive (`l`, `k`, and `m` are not good variable names).

Comment: Also, please post some example input and output.